# await for react-navigation transition to finish

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm looking for a way in react-navigation to dispatch a navigation action and await for it to be fully finished before triggering the next step.

Something like:

```
await dispatch({
  type: 'Navigation/goBackTo',
  routeName: 'Main',
})
dispatch(anotherAction())
```

Currently I'm using a setTimeout workaround.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not specifically related to react-navigation, but useful nonetheless: the **InteractionManager** API from react-native.

There is a method **runAfterInteractions()** which will be called after all animations have been completed, so in case of navigation I find it to be a handy tool. For example you could do something like this:

```
class Main extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // 1: Component has been mounted off-screen
        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
            // 2: Component is done animating
            // 3: Do your anotherAction dispatch() here
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: runAfterInteractions is not solving my problem I don't know why. when I push new screen it hangs for some seconds and then display it. 
I have tried didFocus event handler on react navigation. it solves the problem of hanging but Ui is still take some time to draw on screen

Comment: Could you create another question with your component code and provide the link to it, I am always prepared to take a look at it

Comment: worked for me when I needed to gracefully hide onBoarding component after being watched. thank you

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Android, it just never fires (iOS is fine though). I've set it up exactly as the docs outline: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect#delaying-effect-until-transition-finishes

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a `StackNavigator` you can use [`transitionEnd`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#transitionend) event

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('transitionEnd', (e) => {
    // Do something
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can subscribe to the didFocus event of react-navigation to trigger the second action.

Read about it here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle